# Setting enable-universal-access-from-file-uris for Webkit in TideSDK?

Tags: webkit, tidesdk, opendatabase

Can I set enable-universal-access-from-file-uris=true for Webkit in TideSDK ? Accessing openDatabase from TideSDK causes SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 error.

Comment: Using var db = Ti.Database.open('customdatabase.db'); worked just fine for me on OSX. What system are you on?

Comment: I am on Win 7 x64. And trying to open a pre-populated database file.